# Manjaro/Arch: Disabling IRQ #31 on Thinkpad X1 7th

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kernel, interrupt, irq

I've stumbled upon the beforementioned error during boot and have tried to resolve it by trying to find out what caused the interrupt.
Sadly, `lspci -v | grep 31` gives no result and a `cat /proc/interrupts | grep 31` returns:

```
  31:          0          0          0          0     100000          0          0          0   IO-APIC   31-fasteoi   tpm0
 122:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI 3162112-edge      pciehp
 131:          0          0          0          0          0          0       4780          0   PCI-MSI 1572871-edge      nvme0q7
 136:          0          0          0          0          0          0        377          0   PCI-MSI 520192-edge      enp0s31f6
 160:          0          0          1          0          0          0       1260          0   PCI-MSI 333831-edge      iwlwifi: queue 7
 RES:      25967      11451      13108       4439       3441       4165       4926       4203   Rescheduling interrupts
```

How should I proceed knowing that it maybe has to do something with `IO-APIC 31-fasteoi tpm0`?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini No, unfortunately not. I'd appreciate a push in the right direction though if the solution is that easy and I'm just too stupid to do my research correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, Im also seeing this error on my T490. Will update when I figure something out. I suspect its related to some needed drivers

Comment: I also am seeing this error on T490

Comment: Workaround: disable the Trusted Platform Module in the BIOS.